# Meta APIs Application limit calculation and refresh time

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, instagram-graph-api

**Can someone explain me How does the Meta APIs application limit is calculated and when does it refresh?**

[7 days activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUGqq.png):
*This my Average activity for past 7 days.*

[24 hours active endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J57t3.png):
*This is my most active endpoints for last 24 hours.*

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{ig_user_id}?fields=business_discovery.username({username}){{id,ig_id,profile_picture_url,followers_count,media_count,name,media{{caption,comments_count,timestamp,like_count,media_type,thumb_offset,media_product_type,media_url,permalink}}}}&access_token={access_token}"`

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{page_id}/feed?fields=attachments{{type,media_type,url}},full_picture,status_type,permalink_url,to,message,message_tags,shares,likes.summary(true),comments.limit(3).summary(true),created_time,updated_time&since={start_time}&until={end_time}&access_token={access_token}"`

These are the endpoints that I'm calling.

I'm fetching the previous 7 days or 30 days posts data for 20+ Facebook and Instagram public pages.
Every time I try to run the script, It throws an error saying ***'message': '(#4) Application request limit reached'*** in middle of the script run.

Is there any way to find out the actual calculation metrics of Meta APIs? And the refresh time as well?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting explains what goes into the rate limit calculations.